# Using core-plugins in phonegap build 2.9

Tags: plugins, cordova, contacts, phonegap-build

I'm building a simple app for Windows Phone 8 (with limits me to PG 2.9, since PG 3.0 is not yet supporting WP8).

When I include one of core plugins (3rd party ones work just fine) in my config.xml, I get *"Unable to create app: plugin unsupported"* error.

Changanging PG version to 3.0 fixes problem, and shows included plugin under "Plugins" tab.

So the question is: how to use core plugins in PGB 2.9?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use the plugin tag in your config.xml file for 2.9.0. That's why you're getting the error.

We're planning on rolling out support for Windows Phone 8 in PhoneGap Build by the end of the week so you can use 3.0.0 and not have this issue.

=Ryan
ryan@adobe.com